# Combing sentences with "though" and reasoning with "this is due to"

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-construction, conjunctions

I wrote the following sentences, and I am wondering about the words used to join the fragments together.

> Though 2D shape of a signal post is circular, the minimum rectangle is
>   adopted in lieu of the minimum bounding circle at this instant. This
>   is mainly due to the fine searching  is taken place at a later stage.

1. Here, I am using *though* to join two sentence parts which are related. I am also using some other phrases e.g. *in lieu of*, and I am bit confused whether my sentence is still grammatically correct.
2. If I think about the flow of these two sentences, the second on should come after the first one has happened. I am trying to express this with the phrase “this is mainly due to”, but I feel if I used “this is because of the fine …”, it would make more sense.

Comment: This looks like proofreading to me. My advice is to forget about *in lieu of*, and use *instead of*, [like nearly everybody else](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+lieu+of%2Cinstead+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). As to the rest, I simply don't understand what you're trying to say. An example context that doesn't depend on specialist technical knowledge would be more helpful.

Comment: I think the first sentence is fine as it is, and the second sentence should be "This is _necessary_ due to the fine searching _that_ is _taking_ place at a later stage." or "This _choice is informed by the requirements of_ fine searching that is taking place at a later stage." ----But again, you will be better served by [one of these sites](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/263/alternative-websites-for-proofreading).

Answer (score 1):

First sentence is fine as it is (except of the in lieu of) which could be replaced by instead of.

Honestly I don't understand what is trying to be said in the second sentence and we'd probably need more of the context to comment on your word choice.

Comment: if i Updated the sentence as follows,

> Though 2D shape of a signal post is circular, the minimum rectangle is adopted instead of the minimum bounding circle at this instant particularly to make efficient the initial searching process. then would you think this make sense and error free. thanks. (please don't think as a proof reading.)

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is okay, although "although" would be easier to understand (I don't see many sentences starting with "though"), and 'in lieu' is awfully fancy.

The second sentence is off.

> This is mainly due to the fine search which is taking place at a later stage.
>
> This is mainly because a fine search is taking place at a later stage.

Due to *noun*. Because *sentence*. "Is taking place" or "will take place" in the future; "has taken place" or "took place" before.